# Trouble with randomly generated arrays

Tags: java, arrays, random

So I am working on a assignment that deals with randomly generated arrays. Here is the assignment:

*Write the following function that tests whether a two-dimensional list has four consecutive numbers of the same value, either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values) Write a test program that prompts the user to enter the number of rows and columns of a two-dimensional list and then use a random number generator to fill the array and print it out. Display True if the list contains four consecutive numbers with the same value. Otherwise, display False.*

I got everything else done, and it seems to work, but I am stuck on the randomly generating the array part. What is supposed to happen is the user is supposed to enter in the amount of rows and columns for an array, then it is generated. Then, the array is tested to find out whether or not four consecutive numbers exist. When I come to test the problem, it does not actually display the numbers. I am at a loss, and really confused ( Can anyone help me or give me a hint? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConsecutiveFour {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Random r = new Random();
System.out.print("Enter number of rows: ");
int rows = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter number of columns: ");
int columns = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();


int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];

        // generate some random boolean values        
        boolean[] booleans = new boolean[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < booleans.length; i++) {
            booleans[i] = r.nextBoolean();
        }

        for (boolean b : booleans) {
            System.out.print(b + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

  }
 public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values) {
   boolean cons = false;
  int 
//tests horizontally

for (int r=0; r < rows; r++) {
  for (int c=0; c < columns - 3; c++){
    if (values[c][r] == values[c+1][r] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c+2][r] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c+3][r]) {
      cons = true;
    }
  }
}

//tests vertically
for (int r=0; r < rows - 3; r++) {
  for (int c=0; c < columns; c++){
    if (values[c][r] == values[c][r+1] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c][r+2] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c][r+3]) {
      cons = true;
    }
  }
}

//tests diagonally (going down and to the right)
for (int r=3; r < rows; r++) {
  for (int c=0; c < columns - 3; c++) {
    if (values[c][r] == values[c+1][r-1] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c+2][r-2] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c+3][r-3]) {
      cons = true;
    }
  }
}

//tests diagonally (going down and to the left)
for (int r=0; r < rows - 3; r++) {
  for (int c=0; c < columns - 3; c++) {
    if (values[c][r] == values[c+1][r+1] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c+2][r+2] &&
        values[c][r] == values[c+3][r+3]) {
      cons = true;
    }
  }
}
return cons;
}

}
```

Comment: Not your down voter, but where do you supposedly generate your random numbers? Where do you fill your `matrix` array? You should use your Random object, `r`, for this, and it has a method, `nextInt(int max)` for this. I would do this within nested for loops, right after creating my array, in other words, right after this: `int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];`.

Answer (score 1):

To start both of the *input.nextLine();* lines are unnecessary. Your *input.nextInt();* will be enough to bring in the two values that you need.

It might be easier for you to generate the exact number of random numbers that you need. Seeing how this is an assignment i'll throw you some pseudo code to work through.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int k = 0; i < columns; k++) {
  int ranNum // Generate random number
  // Place random number in matrix[i][k]
  }
}

// Send array through checks
```

Is this the problem you are having or am I misunderstanding your confusion?

Comment: The problem I am having is eventually getting to display the numbers in the output of the code, I'm not sure how to generate them.

Comment: Okay, then simply add something like such after each check statement inside your isConsecutiveFour() method inside the if() statement.

    System.out.println(values[c][r] + "Text if needed");

Then have your return statement return you boolean value so checks are no longer made.

Comment: I just keep on getting a vertical column of zeros.

Comment: That's because your assignment is asking you to generate random *numbers.* Your attempting to generate random boolean values.